# Sort by the last item in array

Tags: node.js, mongodb, sorting, mongoose

I'm trying to sort this by the last item in the array. So that I can sort the person by the most recent year.

This is the function I'm using to return the results.

```
router.get('/', (req, res) => {
  const errors = {};
  Person
    .find()
    .limit(pagingLimit)
    .sort(
      {year:[0]}
    )
    .then(people => {
      if (!people) {
        errors.noprofile = 'There are no profiles';
        res.status(404).json(errors);
      }

      return res.json(people)
    })
    .catch(err => res.status(404).json({
        nopeoplefound: 'No people found'
    }));
});
```

This is an example of the item I'm using to sort.

```
{
  "first_name": "James",
  "last_name": "Smith",
  "years": [
    {
      "year": 2016,
      "sector": "Produce",
      "job_title": "Coroner"
    },
    {
      "year": 2017,
      "sector": "Produce",
      "job_title": "Senior Coroner"
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: Do you want to sort by year? or by last year (e.g. 2017)?

Comment: Either works for me. I would prefer last year so I return the most recent result

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can `$unwind` years via aggregation and then sort by `years: -1`:

```
Person.aggregate([
  { $unwind: "$years" },
  { $sort: { years: -1 }}
]).exec()
.then(result => ...)
```

See it [working here](https://mongoplayground.net/p/154aENDx6vU)